# Thickness of a bar chart

Tags: javascript, plotly

I've been using plot.ly's JavaScript API for a project I've been working on, and I would like to replicate the following chart:

[image]

I've been able to plot it using a bar chart, but the thickness is too great. How can I adjust this accordingly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the layout attribute `bargap` does the trick. It defines the gap between the bars and make the bars itself smaller.
So add it to your layout like this and it should work:

```
var layout={
  bargap: 0.98
}
```

I created an example for you on jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7y3djdsj/

hope it helps:-)

Comment: Diolch yn fawr! Much appreciated :D